# How to deal with Segmentation fault while working with file pointers?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

How can I identify where the problem in the code with SegFault is?

1. Is it a bad practice to send FILE pointers to other functions?
2. Does append mode cause any problem?

Following program is a SIC macro processor, without worrying about the logic about the program can you identify any common errors causing SegFault?

Input.txt(The only input file, remaining files are created by program)

```
SAMPLE  START   1000
MACROS  MACRO   -
SUM     MACRO   &A,&B,&C
-       LDA     &A
-       ADD     &B
-       MOV     &C,&A
-       MEND    -
DIF     MACRO   &A,&B,&C
-       LDA     &A
-       SUB     &B
-       MOV     &C,&A
-       MEND    -
-       MEND    -
-       SUM     TWO,ONE,APLHA
-       SUB     TWO,ONE,BETA
ONE     WORD    1
TWO     WORD    2
ALPHA   RESW    1
BETA    RESW    1
-       END     -
```

If I run this in code blocks it is just creating the file inter.txt but nothing after that is being done. I tried adding a line to inter.txt right after opening it the first time , but that is also not happening (Only empty file is created)

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<ctype.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
void processline(FILE**,FILE**);
void define();
void expand();
char label[10],mn[10],oper[10];

void macrop()
{
    FILE *finter;
    finter=fopen("inter.txt","a+");
    fprintf(finter,"HI");
    FILE *f;
    f=fopen("input.txt","r");
    fscanf(f,"%s%s%s",label,mn,oper);
    fprintf(finter,"%s\t%s\t%s",label,mn,oper);
    fscanf(f,"%s%s%s",label,mn,oper);
    while(strcmp(mn,"END")!=0)
    {
        processline(&f,&finter);
        fscanf(f,"%s%s%s",label,mn,oper);
    }
    fprintf(finter,"%s\t%s\t%s",label,mn,oper);
    fclose(finter);
    fclose(f);
}

void processline(FILE** f,FILE** finter)
{
    FILE *fnam;
    unsigned long int p;
    char name[10];
    fnam=fopen("namtab.txt","r");
    fscanf(fnam,"%s %lu",name,&p);
    while(!feof(fnam))
    {
        if(strcmp(name,label)==0)
        {
            expand(finter,p);
            fclose(fnam);
            return;
        }
    fscanf(fnam,"%s%lu",name,&p);
    }
    if(strcmp(mn,"MACRO")==0)
    {
        fclose(fnam);
        define(f);
    }
    else
    fprintf(*finter,"%s\t%s\t%s",label,mn,oper);
    fclose(fnam);
}
void define(FILE** f)
{
    char *token;
    char *args[10];
    int level,j,i;
    i=0;
    level =1;
    FILE *fdef,*fnam;
    fdef=fopen("deftab.txt","a+");
    fnam=fopen("namtab.txt","a+");
    fprintf(fnam,"%s\t%lu\n",label,ftell(fdef));
    while(level>0)
    {
        fscanf(*f,"%s%s%s",label,mn,oper);
        if(strcmp(mn,"MACRO")==0)
        {
            level+=1;
            fprintf(fnam,"%s\t%lu\n",label,ftell(fdef));
            token=strtok(oper,",");
            while(token!=NULL)
        {
                args[i]=token;
                token=strtok(NULL,",");
                i++;
        }
        }
        else if(strcmp(mn,"MEND")==0)
        {
            level-=1;
            i=0;
            fprintf(fdef,"%s\t%s\t%s\n",label,mn,oper);
        }
        else
        {
        fprintf(fdef,"%s\t%s\t",label,mn);
        token=strtok(oper,",");
        while(token!=NULL)
        {
                if(token[0]=='&')
                {
                    j=0;
                    while(strcmp(token,args[j])!=0)
                    {
                        j++;
                    }
                    fprintf(fdef,"?%d",j);
                }
                else
                {
                fprintf(fdef,"%s\n",token);
                }
            }
        }

    }
    fclose(fdef);
    fclose(fnam);
}
void expand(FILE **finter,unsigned long int p)
{
    FILE * fdef;
    int i,c;
    i=0;
    c=0;
    char * args[10];
    char l[10],m[10],o[10];
    char *token;
    token=strtok(oper,",");
    while(token!=NULL)
    {
        args[i]=token;
        token=strtok(NULL,",");
        i++;
    }
    fdef=fopen("deftab.txt","r");
    fseek(fdef,p,SEEK_SET);
    fscanf(fdef,"%s%s%s",l,m,o);
    while(strcmp(m,"MEND")!=0)
    {
        c=0;
        fprintf(*finter,"%s\t%s\t",l,m);
        token=strtok(o,",");
        while(token!=NULL)
        {
           if(token[0]=='?')
           {
               if(c==1)
               fprintf(*finter,",");
               char a[2];
               a[0]=token[1];
               a[1]='\0';
               fprintf(*finter,"%s",args[atoi(a)]);
    }
            else
            {
                if(c==1)
                fprintf(*finter,",");
                fprintf(fdef,"%s",token);
            }
            c++;
            token=strtok(NULL,",");
        }
        fprintf(*finter,"\n");
        fscanf(fdef,"%s%s%s",l,m,o);
    }
fclose(fdef);
}
int main()
{
    macrop();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "Is it a bad practice to send FILE pointers to other functions?" - NO, in fact it is preferred. That way the file is opened and validated open in the caller before passing the open file stream as a parameter. If the file-open fails -- there is no need to call the function. After the call to `fnam=fopen("namtab.txt","r");` you must validate `if (fnam == NULL) { /* file open failed - handle error */ }` before you first attempt to read from the file stream.

Comment: I would suspect your problem is closely related to not having learned [**Why is while ( !feof (file) ) always wrong?**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong). Make the changes needed and then edit your question (do not delete any of the original), and ***add*** your new results at the bottom of your current question.

Comment: Use a debugger like GDB while compiling the program

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I identify where the problem in the code with SegFault is?

You run it under debugger. On Linux, [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) is the most often used one. [LLDB](https://lldb.llvm.org/) can also be used.

If you are on a supported platform, you could also build your program with [Address Sanitizer](https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/AddressSanitizer) (`-fsanitize=address`), which will likely point you straight at your bug(s).

> Is it a bad practice to send FILE pointers to other functions?

Not at all. Passing `FILE **` is quite unusual though.

> Does append mode cause any problem?

Probably not. Your program requires a bunch of input files, and you didn't provide their contents, so it's impossible to tell where your program crashes for you.

> Following program is a SIC macro processor, without worrying about the logic about the program can you identify any common errors causing SegFault?

The common errors I see:

1. Not checking the result of `fopen` (this causes your program to crash for me -- I didn't create all the required files).
2. Using `fscanf` with very small input buffers -- if the strings that you read are longer than 10 characters, you'll have buffer overflows galore. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1621973/50617) on how to avoid that.